# Printing multi-page HTML with absolute positions

Tags: c#, html, css, printing, crystal-reports

I was tasked to convert a Crystal Report that would print pick tickets to an HTML (and/or PDF) report instead.  Part of the reason is the DLL hell that is CR and some overt complexities in the original report we don't need.

This is not quite a direct question though it can turn into one.  I have completed the project and have it working such that it processes a a set of HTML for each page, filling in data fields, then using iText7 converting it to PDF and merging the pages into one large file.  When done I then use Sumantra PDF to print (this way I can control printer settings).

The template I use was generated by Crystal Reports and set all DIV elements as absolute positions.

```
    <div id="hdr_salesorder_title" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:444px;left:19px;width:133px;height:16px;"><span class="hdr_bold_italic">Sales Order Number:</span></div>
    <div id="hdr_salesorder_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:463px;left:19px;width:133px;height:17px;"><span class="hdr_std_text">@SALESORDER</span></div>
    <div id="hdr_shipdate_title" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:444px;left:153px;width:67px;height:17px;"><span class="hdr_bold_italic">Ship Date</span></div>
    <div id="hdr_shipdate" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:463px;left:153px;width:72px;height:17px;"><span class="hdr_std_text">@SHIPDATE</span></div>
```

My original idea was to save each page to an HTML file and using the webbrowser control, print out the total set of pages, but the absolute top and lefts basically had all pages print on top of each other.

I researched the media css style

```
@media print {
  .page-breaker { 
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

but the absolute overrode the page break.  Short of going through a very complex html file and doing substitution of top and left for every page is there a way to tell the print/browser that each page break is a new top?  Going the substitution approach worries me if I don't get the offsets per page right.

What I got working now is:

- Open the template and split out the sections
- Get the data
- Loop through the data seeding data to replace placesetters.

  - convert html to PDF using iText7
  - Merge page to main pdf document using iText7
- When done with all the data
- Save the document
- Open the document with Sumantra PDF
- print the document using Sumantra PDF.

My concern is that when I run the CR report and save the PDF the file size is almost 2/3'rds less the size of the iText7 file.  The process may need to deal with over 1000+ pages of tickets and I am concerned of blowing up network and printer limits.  Printing HTML direct seems to be a more efficient approach than PDF,smaller file, less impact on systems, but I'm stuck on getting around absolute top and lefts.

I am also open to other ideas as it relates to HTML changes.  I am no expert on CSS or html though I am versed in it.  Crystal Reports is a hell me and my company would like to get away from for both the cost and that we only use it for one report.  I am including the html template I use for the report.  The detail lines are dynamic and the footer section needs to be at the bottom of every page which is why I worry about relative positioning.

If this is the best I got I keep it, but I'm hoping someone else may have a different approach that I can make work that will not be so resource intensive.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Crystal Reports 14.0">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre Barcode 39' rel='stylesheet'>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <style>
        div {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 25
        }

        a {
            text-decoration: none
        }

            a img {
                border-style: none;
                border-width: 0
            }

        .relativeContainer {
            position: relative;
        }

        .block {
            height: 12px;
            width: 220px;
            display: block;
        }

        .relative {
            position: relative;
        }

        .std_text {
            font-size: 8pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .tote_text {
            font-size: 18pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .acc_text {
            font-size: 18pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .hdr_std_text {
            font-size: 9pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .hdr_bold_italic {
            font-size: 9pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        .hdr_title_text {
            font-size: 6pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .hdr_barcode {
            font-size: 30pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39';
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .hdr_non_barcode {
            font-size: 19pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: 'Century Schoolbook';
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .hdr_special1 {
            font-size: 9pt;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .dtl_hdr_top {
            top: 574px;
        }

        .hdr_addr_top {
            top: 386px;
        }

        .itm_hdr_text {
            font-size: 7pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .item_bold_sm {
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .item_sm {
            font-size: 10pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .item_bold_lg {
            font-size: 11pt;
            color: #000000;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .std_div {
            border-color: #000000;
            border-left-width: 0;
            border-right-width: 0;
            border-top-width: 0;
            border-bottom-width: 0;
        }

        @page {
            margin-top: 0pt;
            margin-left: 0pt;
            margin-right: 0pt;
            margin-bottom: 0pt;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="hdr_second_page" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:230px;left:200px;width:400px;height:32px;@HDRSHOW"><span class="item_bold_lg">THIS SECTION LEFT INTENTIONALLY BLANK</span></div>
    <div id="hdr_firstpage" style="z-index:3;top:0;left:0;@HDRCLEAR;">
        <div id="hdr_main" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,768px,432px,0px);top:60px;left:15px;width:768px;height:432px;"></div>
        <div id="hdr_addressinfo_header" style="z-index:10;top:384px;left:224px;width:552px;height:17px;border-radius: 5px; border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;background-color:#c0c0c0;layer-background-color:#c0c0c0;"></div>
        <!-- this section creates all the vertical lines for the grids -->
        <div id="hdr_spacer4" style="z-index:15;top:372px;left:23px;border-color:#000000;border-style:dotted;border-width:0px;border-top-width:1px;width:738px;"></div>
        <div id="hdr_spacer3" style="z-index:15;top:384px;left:407px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,94px,0px);height:94px;"></div>
        <div id="hdr_spacer2" style="z-index:15;top:384px;left:587px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,94px,0px);height:94px;"></div>
        <div id="hdr_spacer1" style="z-index:15;top:68px;left:400px;border-color:#000000;border-style:dotted;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,304px,0px);height:304px;"></div>
        <div id="middle_spacer2" style="z-index:15;top:492px;left:95px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,78px,0px);height:78px;"></div>
        <div id="middle_spacer1" style="z-index:15;top:492px;left:375px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,78px,0px);height:78px;"></div>
        <!-- end spacer section -->
        <div id="hdr_carousel" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:64px;left:23px;width:50px;height:16px;"><span class="std_text">@ISCAROUSEL</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_weborderid_left_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:132px;left:271px;width:114px;height:16px;"><span class="std_text">@CUSORDREF_0</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_weborderid_right_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:132px;left:655px;width:114px;height:16px;"><span class="std_text">@CUSORDREF_0</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_soldto_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:404px;left:231px;width:177px;height:75px;">
            @DIVBILLTOADDRESS
        </div>
        <div id="hdr_salesorder_title" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:444px;left:19px;width:133px;height:16px;"><span class="hdr_bold_italic">Sales Order Number:</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_salesorder_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:463px;left:19px;width:133px;height:17px;"><span class="hdr_std_text">@SALESORDER</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_shipdate_title" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:444px;left:153px;width:67px;height:17px;"><span class="hdr_bold_italic">Ship Date</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_shipdate" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:463px;left:153px;width:72px;height:17px;"><span class="hdr_std_text">@SHIPDATE</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_address_info" style="z-index:10;top:384px;left:224px;width:552px;height:92px;border-radius: 5px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;"></div>
        <div id="hdr_Address_header1" class="std_div hdr_addr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:281px;width:82px;height:13px;"><span class="hdr_title_text">SOLD TO</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_Address_header2" class="std_div hdr_addr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:448px;width:82px;height:13px;"><span class="hdr_title_text">SHIP TO</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_Address_header3" class="std_div hdr_addr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:605px;width:82px;height:13px;"><span class="hdr_title_text">TOTE #</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_shipTo_right_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:150px;left:550px;width:220px;height:83px;">
            @DIVSHIPTOADDRESS
        </div>
        <div id="hdr_shipid_barcode_left_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:268px;left:167px;width:133px;height:12px;"><span class="hdr_title_text">@SHIPPINGID</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_shipid_barcode_right_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:268px;left:551px;width:133px;height:12px;"><span class="hdr_title_text">@SHIPPINGID</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_custid_barcode_right_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:268px;left:695px;width:80px;height:12px;"><span class="hdr_title_text">@CUSTOMERID</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_custid_barcode_left_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:268px;left:319px;width:80px;height:12px;"><span class="hdr_title_text">@CUSTOMERID</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_operator_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:459px;left:593px;width:75px;height:17px;"><span class="std_text">OPR = @OPR</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_pod_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:459px;left:679px;width:75px;height:17px;"><span class="std_text">POD = @POD</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_tote_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:425px;left:630px;width:100px;height:25px;"><span class="tote_text">@TOTE</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_barcode_left_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:230px;left:167px;width:228px;height:32px;"><span class="hdr_@NONbarcode">@BARSHIPPINGID</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_barcode_right_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:230px;left:551px;width:228px;height:32px;"><span class="hdr_@NONbarcode">@BARSHIPPINGID</span></div>
        <div id="hdr_shipTo_left_data" class="std_div relativeContainer" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:150px;left:166px;width:220px;height:83px;">
            @DIVSHIPTOADDRESS
        </div>
        <div id="hdr_shipto_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:403px;left:412px;width:172px;height:73px;">
            @DIVSHIPTOADDRESS
        </div>
        <div id="hdr_batchId_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:409px;left:599px;width:167px;height:17px;"><span class="hdr_std_text">@BATCHID</span></div>
        <div id="logo_left" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPTpx;left:@LEFTLpx;width:@TOPWpx;height:@TOPHpx;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\logo_@LOGO.png" border="0" width="@TOPWpx" height="@TOPHpx"></div>
        <div id="logo_right" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPTpx;left:@LEFTRpx;width:@TOPWpx;height:@TOPHpx;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\logo_@LOGO.png" border="0" width="@TOPWpx" height="@TOPHpx"></div>
        <div id="logo_middle" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPMpx;left:@LEFTMpx;width:@MIDWpx;height:@MIDHpx;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\logo_@LOGO.png" border="0" width="@MIDWpx" height="@MIDHpx"></div>
        <div id="agro_left" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:24;top:124px;left:111px;width:151px;height:21px; display:@DISPLAY;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\agro_message.png" border="0" width="151px" height="21px"></div>
        <div id="agro_right" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:24;top:124px;left:495px;width:147px;height:18px; display:@DISPLAY;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\agro_message.png" border="0" width="147px" height="18px"></div>
        <div id="inspection_left" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:-1;top:150px;left:23px;width:134px;height:134px; display:@DISPLAY;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\inspection_sticker.png" border="0" width="134px" height="134px"></div>
        <div id="inspection_right" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:-1;top:150px;left:407px;width:134px;height:134px; display:@DISPLAY;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\inspection_sticker.png" border="0" width="134px" height="134px"></div>
        <div id="meets_left" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:284px;left:19px;width:376px;height:82px; display:@DISPLAY;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\meets_standards.png" border="0" width="376px" height="82px"></div>
        <div id="meets_right" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:284px;left:403px;width:376px;height:82px; display:@DISPLAY;"><img src="C:\temp\PickTicketHTML\images\meets_standards.png" border="0" width="376px" height="82px"></div>
        <div id="middle_main" style="z-index:10;top:492px;left:17px;width:758px;height:75px;border-radius: 5px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;"></div>
        <div id="middle_space" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,768px,77px,0px);top:492px;left:15px;width:768px;height:77px;"></div>
        <div id="middle_canada_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:514px;left:25px;width:48px;height:16px;"><span class="hdr_special1">@CAN</span></div>
        <div id="middle_state_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:547px;left:25px;width:48px;height:25px;"><span class="mid_special">@STATE</span></div>
        <div id="middle_acc_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:495px;left:25px;width:48px;height:30px;"><span class="acc_text">@ACC</span></div>
        <div id="middle_text1_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:495px;left:378px;width:390px;height:70px;"><span class="std_text">@SOH1TEXT</span></div>
        <div id="middle_text2_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:495px;left:97px;width:390px;height:70px;"><span class="std_text">@SOH2TEXT</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="detail_header_titles" style="z-index:10;top:569px;left:15px;width:759px;height:24px;border-radius: 5px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;background-color:#c0c0c0;layer-background-color:#c0c0c0;"></div>
    <div id="detail_headers" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,768px,28px,0px);top:569px;left:15px;width:768px;height:28px;"></div>
    <div id="detail_spacer5" style="z-index:15;top:569px;left:95px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,26px,0px);height:26px;" /></div>
    <div id="detail_space4" style="z-index:15;top:569px;left:167px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,26px,0px);height:26px;"></div>
    <div id="detail_space3" style="z-index:15;top:569px;left:247px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,26px,0px);height:26px;"></div>
    <div id="detail_space2" style="z-index:15;top:569px;left:375px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,26px,0px);height:26px;"></div>
    <div id="detail_space1" style="z-index:15;top:569px;left:695px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-left-width:1px;clip:rect(0px,1px,26px,0px);height:26px;"></div>
    <div id="detail_hdr_location" class="std_div dtl_hdr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:27px;width:52px;height:16px;"><span class="itm_hdr_text">Location</span></div>
    <div id="detail_hdr_shipped" class="std_div dtl_hdr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:103px;width:49px;height:16px;"><span class="itm_hdr_text">Shipped</span></div>
    <div id="detail_hdr_backord" class="std_div dtl_hdr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:183px;width:45px;height:16px;"><span class="itm_hdr_text">Bckord</span></div>
    <div id="detail_hdr_itemnumber" class="std_div dtl_hdr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:255px;width:112px;height:16px;"><span class="itm_hdr_text">Item&nbsp;Number</span></div>
    <div id="detail_hdr_description" class="std_div dtl_hdr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:431px;width:180px;height:16px;"><span class="itm_hdr_text">Description</span></div>
    <div id="detail_hdr_origin" class="std_div dtl_hdr_top" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;left:703px;width:48px;height:16px;"><span class="itm_hdr_text">Origin</span></div>
    <!-- D1 Start of Detail template, do not remove these comments.  This section is removed and replaced by the program -->
    <div id="detail_line" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,768px,17px,0px);top:@TOPDpx;left:15px;width:768px;height:17px;"></div>
    <div id="detail_location_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPDpx;left:16px;width:79px;height:15px;"><span class="item_bold_lg">@LOCATION</span></div>
    <div id="detail_qty_shipped_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPDpx;left:103px;width:64px;height:16px;text-align:center;"><span class="item_bold_lg">@QTYSHIP</span></div>
    <div id="detail_qty_backord_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPDpx;left:175px;width:64px;height:16px;text-align:center;"><span class="item_bold_lg">@QTYBACKORD</span></div>
    <div id="detail_itemnumber_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPDpx;left:263px;width:103px;height:16px;"><span class="item_bold_sm">@ITEMNUM</span></div>
    <div id="detail_description_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPDpx;left:375px;width:320px;height:16px;"><span class="item_sm">@DESCRIPTION</span></div>
    <div id="detail_origin_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPDpx;left:695px;width:80px;height:16px;"><span class="item_sm">@ORIGIN    @OSTATE</span></div>
    <!-- D1X End of Detail template -->
    <!-- D2 start of detail text line, do not remove these comments.  This section is removed and replaced by the program -->
    <div id="detail_line_text" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,768px,17px,0px);top:@TOPDpx;left:15px;width:768px;height:17px;"></div>
    <div id="detail_text_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:@TOPDpx;left:16px;width:760px;height:15px;"><span class="std_text">@DETTEXT</span></div>
    <!-- D2X End of Detail text line -->
    @DETAILLINE
    <div id="footer_main" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,768px,77px,0px);top:1010px;left:15px;width:768px;height:96px;border-radius: 5px;border-color:#000000;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;"></div>
    <div id="footer_text_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1015px;left:31px;width:768px;height:15px;"><span class="std_text">@SOH2TEXT</span></div>
    <div id="footer_totalshipped_title" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1032px;left:31px;width:38px;height:15px;">
        <table width="38px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <td align="left"><span class="item_bold_sm">TSHP:</span></td>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="footer_weborderid_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1032px;left:127px;width:110px;height:15px;"><span class="std_text">@CUSORDREF_0</span></div>
    <div id="footer_timeprinted_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1032px;left:671px;width:64px;height:15px;"><span class="std_text">@TIMEPRINT</span></div>
    <div id="footer_dateprinted_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1032px;left:247px;width:68px;height:15px;"><span class="std_text">@DATEPRINT</span></div>
    <div id="footer_cusstomerid_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1032px;left:575px;width:74px;height:15px;"><span class="std_text">@CUSTOMERID</span></div>
    <div id="footer_totalshipped_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1032px;left:71px;width:42px;height:15px;text-align:right;"><span class="std_text">@TOTLINES</span></div>
    <div id="footer_bottom" style="z-index:3;clip:rect(0px,768px,16px,0px);top:1052px;left:15px;width:768px;height:16px;"></div>
    <div id="footer_shipid_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1052px;left:314px;width:92px;height:16px;"><span class="std_text">@SHIPPINGID</span></div>
    <div id="footer_batchid_data" class="std_div" nowrap="true" style="z-index:25;top:1052px;left:559px;width:200px;height:16px;"><span class="hdr_std_text">@BATCHID</span></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

*This template is a nightmare...*
Ad rem:
You have to overwrite the `absolute` - thanks to the cascade it should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">             <!-- here other meta's -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" ..."          <!-- basic css file -->

    <!-- for printer only, it must be the last one css to overwrite other css-->
<link media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="print.css">
```

print.css

```
div{ position: static}      /* or relative - test, your css is too much complicated to guess what you need */

.never{ display: none}      /* for elements you never want to print */
.always{ position: fixed}   /* for elements you want to print on each page */
```

other way - put needed declaration(s) at the bottom of `<style> ...</style>` in the `head` of page - it must be the last one css declaration.
I used example classes, but you can close `div`s in 3 areas like `header, main, footer` or select them direct by id, then in css (file or style part) set them properties for printing.
You can set printing properties for any page element, no need to build 'special' version manually, just make complete print.css for existing page - exclude etc with css selecting by class or id. This css file will only be applied for printing and will only do what you order.
`Page-break` usually works, but just breaks page on the selected line, nothing else.

... this template is a nightmare [Validator](https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/) w3c